# Union of two lists in LINQ not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, union

I've a method where I'll show the books which are present in the db and the ones which are given for lent.

When the user doesn't returns the book,the book becomes inactive.So I've written a LINQ query where the new users can select a book.Then if the the user selects a lost book.He will be thrown a message that the book is not available.

Here I am using the Union to find the books which are active and the books which are lent and not return.

But the duplicate values  are returning in method.

```
public IEnumerable<UsageType> GetUsageType(int BookID = 0)
        {
            _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            List<UsageType> Uresult = new List<UsageType>();
            List<UsageType> result = new List<UsageType>();
            try
            {
                if (BookID == 0)
                {
                    result = (from Usage in _db.USAGE_TYPE
                              where Usage.IS_ACTIVE == true
                              select new
                              {
                                  UsageTypeId = Usage.USAGE_TYPE_ID,
                                  UsageTypeName = Usage.USAGE_TYPE_NAME,
                                  IsActive = Usage.IS_ACTIVE
                              }).AsEnumerable()
                                          .Select(x => new UsageType
                                          {
                                              UsageTypeId = x.UsageTypeId,
                                              UsageTypeName = x.UsageTypeName,
                                              IsActive = x.IsActive.HasValue ? x.IsActive.Value : false
                                          }).Distinct().ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (from Usage in _db.USAGE_TYPE
                              where Usage.IS_ACTIVE == true
                              select new
                              {
                                  UsageTypeId = Usage.USAGE_TYPE_ID,
                                  UsageTypeName = Usage.USAGE_TYPE_NAME,
                                  IsActive = Usage.IS_ACTIVE
                              }).AsEnumerable()
                                     .Select(x => new UsageType
                                     {
                                         UsageTypeId = x.UsageTypeId,
                                         UsageTypeName = x.UsageTypeName,
                                         IsActive = x.IsActive.HasValue ? x.IsActive.Value : false
                                     }).ToList();

                    var savedUsagetype = (from Usage in _db.USAGE_TYPE
                                          join usageCategory in _db.USAGE_CATEGORY on Usage.USAGE_TYPE_ID equals usageCategory.USAGE_TYPE_ID
                                          join book_usage in _db.BOOK_USAGE
                                          on usageCategory.USAGE_CATEGORY_ID equals book_usage.USAGE_CATEGORY_ID
                                          where book_usage.Book_ID == BookID 
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              UsageTypeId = Usage.USAGE_TYPE_ID,
                                              UsageTypeName = Usage.USAGE_TYPE_NAME,
                                              IsActive = Usage.IS_ACTIVE
                                          }).AsEnumerable()
                                       .Select(x => new UsageType
                                       {
                                           UsageTypeId = x.UsageTypeId,
                                           UsageTypeName = x.UsageTypeName,
                                           IsActive = x.IsActive.HasValue ? x.IsActive.Value : false
                                       }).ToList();



                Uresult= result.Union(savedUsagetype).Distinct().ToList();
                }

                return Uresult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The `.Union(...)` is executed in-memory, not by the database. This means that the in-memory objects are compared, which means you need to write a comparer. Otherwise it will be done compare-by-reference, which explain the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing objects of your own class so you should implement `IEquatable` in your `UsageType` class to tell linq *how* to compare your objects. For example:

```
public class UsageType : IEquatable<UsageType>
{
    public int UsageTypeId {get; set;}
    ...

    public bool Equals(UsageType other)
    {
       return this.UsageTypeId == other.UsageTypeId;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
       return this.UsageTypeId == ((UsageType)other).UsageTypeId;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    { 
       return this.UsageTypeId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can use `UsageType` to get an instance of `IEqualityComparer<UsageType>`:

```
Uresult = result.Union(savedUsageType,IEqualityComparer<UsageType>.Default).ToList();
```

**Note:** Always override `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashcode()` too. If you don't, old code which still uses the non-generic `Enumerable` will give unexpected results because they use other logic to compare than you'd expect.